# How to preg_match_all the images which has a http head width>100px and height>80px?

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing

I want to match all `img`s that:

1. Have one of the extensions: jpg|png|gif
2. Whose `src` do not begin with `http://`
3. Whose width > 100 and height > 100

I started with this regular expression:

```
preg_match_all("/(href|src)=([\"|']?)([^ \"'>]+\.(jpg|png|gif))\\2/i",$str,$matches);
```

Comment: What if image tags have no width or height attribute set?

Comment: I would prefer a regex that can parse that question.

Comment: @Nick Weaver, my images all have width or height attribute, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numeric comparisions in regular expressions are not that simple, and finding width= and height= attributes would necessitate a way more complex regular expression. See [regex tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world)

Hence this is one of the cases where a simpler HTML parser would make sense. For example with [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) you could use:

```
foreach (qp($html)->find("img, a") as $img) {
    if ($img->attr("width") >= 100 and ...) {
        echo $img->attr("src"), $img->attr("href");
    }
}
```

Of course using DOMDocument would be faster (and also more typing..)

Comment: thank you, but use `$html->find("img, a")` can not match whether the image is a `http` begain, may be they chould like ` ../imgaes/1.jpg`

Comment: actually this script only dumps the values of the src or href attribute. it doesn' care whether it's a relative path or starts with https...

Comment: @cj333 Add an extra `if` for more rules, or use `->find('img[src^="http"]')` for filtering.